# How to perform pandas-like merge in xarray?

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have one long dataframe with a single duplicated dimension (country) and default index and one 2D dataframe sharing same dimension (country) and having an extra one (time)

I want to left merge the two objects in a xr.DataSet so that each default index from the left object is associated with exactly 1 vector (over time) from the right object according to the matching country

When I perform the merge using xarray and I select a specific default index from the left object I obtain all possible combinations of the 2nd object without taking into account the corresponding country. Example shows the desired result using pandas:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'country': 4*['UK','US','FR','DE'],
    'var1': 10*np.arange(16),
}).reset_index(names='N')

ds1 = df1.set_index(['N','country']).to_xarray()


df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'country': 4*['UK'] + 4*['US'] + 4*['FR'] + 4*['DE'],
    'time': 4*list(pd.timedelta_range(
        start='30D',
        periods=4,
        freq='30D'
    )),
    'var2': 20*np.arange(16),    
})

ds2 = df2.set_index(['country','time']).to_xarray()

# 1. xarray merge
ds3 = ds1.merge(ds2, join='left')
# Selecting specific original index
# returns all possible combinations without recognising corresponding country
display(ds3.sel(N=1).var2)

# 2. pandas merge
df3 = df1.set_index(['N','country']).merge(
    df2.pivot(index='country', columns='time'),
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True
)
# Selecting specific original index
# returns only vector for corresponding country
df3.xs(1, level='N')
```